# How do I resolve this issue "NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type..."?

Tags: android, twilio, sms

```
  Process: com.example.thesisbuyer, PID: 22196
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)
```

That is the error message I get when calling this method

```
public void sendTwilioNotifJava(){

        String ACCOUNT_ID = "My_ID";
        String Twilio_Auth_Token = "My_Token";
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_ID, Twilio_Auth_Token);

        Message message = Message.creator(
                new PhoneNumber("Receiver_Num"),
                new PhoneNumber("Twilio_Num"),
                "This is a sample message"
        ).create();

        Log.d(TAG, "sendTwilioNotifJava: "+message.getSid());
    }
```

Also, I have tried calling an equivalent kotlin function for this and it also gives me the same error message.